# Trying to build a drop down menu within PHP array

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to build a PHP function that creates a drop down inside an array. The theme I'm using gave me an example on how to add custom data to fields and I'm trying to then modify that to add a drop down menu. I'm not even sure if it's possible. The code I have creates the drop down box but doesn't have any data in it.

Here is my code:

```
function frontend_add_timezone_field( $fields ) {
    $fields['job']['timezone'] = array(
      'label'       => __( 'Your Timezone', 'job_manager' ),
      timezone        => array('(GMT-10:00) Hawaii', '(GMT-09:00) Alaska', '(GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada)' ),
      'priority'    => 7
  ); 
 echo '<select name="timezon">';
   for($i = 0; $i < count($timezone);$i++)
    {
        echo '<option value="'. ($i + 1) .'">' .$timezone{$i} . '</option>';
    }
 echo '</select>';
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Where is the value for $timezone established?  It seems to me that this might require more experimentation on your part.

Comment: I thought I was establishing it right there within the array.. am I not able to do that?

Comment: It was established as a key name for the array.  See Sarah's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As gladiola commented there is missing $timezone. You have established it inside $fields['job']['timezone']. In other words $timezone is in your case

`$timezone = $fields['job']['timezone']['timezone'];`

After this the code works for me.

Comment: Thank you for all your help!